# mysql left join subselect

Tags: mysql, database, select

I have table in this format:

```
tag | item
----------
1   | 1
2   | 2
2   | 3
3   | 1
3   | 2
3   | 3
```

I have to select those tags, which are present in set of items in every one of it.

For example:

items={2,3} --> tags{2,3}, item 2 has tags 2,3, item 3 has tags 2,3, common tags are 2,3

items={1,2,3} --> tags{}, item 1 has tags 1,3, item 2 has tags 2,3, item 3 has tags 2,3, common tags are 3

items={1,3} --> tags{3}, item 1 has tags 1,3, item 3 has tags 2,3, common tags are 3

As input I have set of items. I have no idea how to write such query.

Thank you for response.

Comment: So you give a list of items and you want common tags for that list? Or just a list of items and common tags?

Comment: i have a list of items and want a common tag

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for lists of items that share the same tags, right?

This query should do it for you.  It's made up of an inner summary query that groups together the tags for each item, then an outer summary query that groups together the items that share tag-groups.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(item ORDER by ITEM) items, tags
  FROM (
           SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(tag ORDER BY tag) tags, item
             FROM tbl
         GROUP BY item
        )t
  GROUP BY tags
  ORDER BY tags
```

It returns, for your test dataset in your question:

```
| ITEMS | TAGS |
----------------
|     1 |  1,3 |
|   2,3 |  2,3 |
```

That is, your item 1 has tags 1 and 3.  Your items 2 and 3 have tags 2 and 3.

Go fiddle! http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6a927/3/0

Comment: I have a list of items and I want to find out, which items share the same tags, I am not looking for all the possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

The query to solve your problem is (assuming no duplicate entries for tag and item)

```
SELECT tag FROM <table_name>
WHERE item IN (<items to be searched seperated by ,>)
GROUP BY tag
HAVING COUNT(*) = <number of items>;
```

e.g. for items {1,3}

```
SELECT tag FROM <table_name>
WHERE item IN (1,3)
GROUP BY tag
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```

for items {1,2,3}

```
SELECT tag FROM <table_name>
WHERE item IN (1,2,3)
GROUP BY tag
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3;
```

For seeing results seperated by comma use following query

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(a.tag) FROM (
SELECT tag FROM <table_name>
WHERE item IN (<items to be searched seperated by comma>)
GROUP BY tag
HAVING COUNT(*) = <no. of items>) AS a;
```

Hope it helps...